# Serve Static Files from Node.js with POST data

Tags: json, node.js, static-html, node-static

I run a node.js server, and use node-static to serve static HTML files.

```
var nodeStatic = require('node-static');
var file = new nodeStatic.Server('./public');
..
file.serveFile('/file.html', 500, {}, request, response);
```

What i would like to do is, serve a static HTML file with a set of variables attached (e.g. over the POST method). I want to include dynamic information in the HTML file, and would like to be able to hand over that dynamic data - ideally in JSON format - from the node server.

Can node-static do that? Or is there another module out there that can?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is templating. It can be done in both client-side and server-side. (Jade is my favorite) But the client-side performance can be unsatisfying sometimes. Here have a look at these [Client-Side Template Engine Benchmarks](http://jsperf.com/dom-vs-innerhtml-based-templating/53).